# Unable to see event counters for [Microsoft|System].Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclient

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/event-counters?view=sql-server-ver15) I should be able to use the `dotnet counters` tool to view the event counters for `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` (similarly for `System.Data.SqlClient`).

For example using

```
dotnet-counters monitor Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.EventSource 
      -p <process-id> --refresh-interval 3
```

where `process-id` is the `dotnet` process I want to monitor.

However - all I see is:

> Status: Waiting for initial payload...

**Note**: other counters work fine

```
E:\src>dotnet counters --version
6.0.257301+27172ce4d05e8a3b0ffdefd65f073d40a1b1fe54

E:\src>dotnet --version
6.0.200
```

Comment: Have you tried running with elevated right?

Comment: For those who run by this question and are curious: When I've run into this issue, it's usually because I'm pulling from the wrong namespace. Ensure that you are using SqlConnection from Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and not System.Data.SqlClient. If you're using the SqlClientFactory, again, ensure that you are using it from the Microsoft and not System namespaces. The NuGet package contains both and any old code, won't tick an error during compile time.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue

Comment: @RobL - so long ago can't remember - but I've just checked - and it works for me now - dotnet 7 / Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.1